# How to ask for a specific share of turtles with a minimum share of a value?

Tags: if-statement, netlogo, min, percentage, agent-based-modeling

I've set up firms (turtles) in an industry (world) which either produce at home (firms-at-home located > ycor) or have offshored their production (offshore-firms located < ycor). I have given them a firms-own called offshored? which is answered with either true or false. At setup, they also get a firms-own firm-level-of-automation which is random between 0 and 1.

Now, I would like to have 30 % of them with the lowest firm-level-of-automation to move production to < 0 ycor and report: offshored? = true

```
breed [ firms firm ]

firms-own [
 firm-level-of-automation   ;; initially random between 0 and 1
 offshored?   ;; true or false
]

to go
tick
ask firms [
 set firm-level-of-automation 0 + random-float 1

 if min [ firm-level-of-automation ] of firms [
   count firms * 0.3 firms [ setxy random-xcor random-between ( -10 ) -1   ;; distribute randomly abroad in an area < 0 ycor
   set offshored? true ] ] ]
end
```

I don't know how to mix the `if` and `min` command best here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are being down voted for this, it seems like a sensible question. Anyway, there is no need to mix `min` and `if`, you can simply `ask` the 30% of turtles with the lower values to do what you want. Look up the `min-n-of` primitive in the dictionary, you will want something like:

```
ask min-n-of (0.3 * count firms) firms [firm-level-of-automation]
[ setxy random-xcor random-between ( -10 ) -1 
  set offshored? true
]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying anyhow. You suggestions worked, thanks a lot!